# How to show a dilaog when app returns from background and not when back button is pressed

Tags: android

I need to show a dialog when my app returns from the background for that I have implemented following code in my activity:

```
 Boolean paused=false;
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    paused=true;
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    if(paused){
        paused=false;
        PinInptDialog dialog = new PinInptDialog(this);
        dialog.show();
    }
    super.onResume();
}
```

Problem is it works fine for app coming from background but My project has a number of activities while navigating from one activity to another if I press back key this dialog is opening which I want to avoid Please suggest me;

Comment: can you add another flag and set true when back button pressed and in on resume check pause and backbutton flag

Comment: need to override onBackPressed in every activity but thank you I will try that too

Comment: I think thats the better way match two falgs condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override onBackPressed of those activties & make pause = false.
You have to make pause a global variable where all activities can access it.
I suggest to use a sharedpreference.

```
onBackPressed(){
pause = false;
super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: had to use the combination of one flag in sharedPreference and one local flag

Answer (score 0):

Before starting a new activity make the `paused = false;` so that it won't show the dialog when returning to this activity

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to create a boolean variable in your application class rather than activity class. Then on every on pause set the variable to true and on every resume set check for the variable.